# Can't process set operations after client evaluation efcore

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Ef Core receiving error

> System.InvalidOperationException: Can't process set operations after
> client evaluation, consider moving the operation before the last
> Select() call (see issue #16243)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SelectExpression.ApplySetOperation(SetOperationType
> setOperationType, SelectExpression select2, Boolean distinct)

when executing

```
 public async Task<object> GetUnitsForDataTableAsync() =>
        
            await context.Units
             .Where(x => !x.TractUnitJunctions.Any())
              .Select(x => new
              {
                  x.Id,
                  x.UnitName,
                  x.UnitAcres,
                  TractNum = String.Empty,
                  Wells = String.Empty,
                  NumOfWells = 0,
              })
              .Union(
                        context.TractUnitJunctions
                        .Select(x => new
                         {
                            Id = x.UnitId,
                            x.Unit.UnitName,
                            x.Unit.UnitAcres,
                            x.Tract.TractNum,
                            Wells = string.Join(", ", x.TractUnitJunctionWellJunctions
                                              .Select(z => $"{z.Well.WellNum} ({z.Well.ApiNum})")
                                        ),
                            NumOfWells = x.TractUnitJunctionWellJunctions.Count()
                 }))
                .ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

however the function works fine if I break it up into two queries.

```
 public async Task<object> GetUnitsForDataTableAsync()
        {
            var List1 = await context.Units
             .Where(x => !x.TractUnitJunctions.Any())
              .Select(x => new
              {
                  x.Id,
                  x.UnitName,
                  x.UnitAcres,
                  TractNum = String.Empty,
                  Wells = String.Empty,
                  NumOfWells = 0,
              })
             .ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            var List2 = await context.TractUnitJunctions
                 .Select(x => new
                 {
                     Id = x.UnitId,
                     x.Unit.UnitName,
                     x.Unit.UnitAcres,
                     x.Tract.TractNum,
                     Wells = string.Join(", ", x.TractUnitJunctionWellJunctions
                                              .Select(z => $"{z.Well.WellNum} ({z.Well.ApiNum})")
                                        ),
                     NumOfWells = x.TractUnitJunctionWellJunctions.Count()
                 })
                .ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);


            return List1.Concat(List2);
        }
```

I've researched that error a bit but I'm unsure how to refactor the first query to get around that error

Comment: you probably should move `string.Join` logic after `.ToList()`. this is EF Core <= 2.2, right?

Comment: *I'm unsure how to refactor* -- Well, you did. And that's the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accepted answer while it works is flawed in that you're eager loading the first list.

This is a known bug which you should be able to resolve by moving the Where clause after the Union

As discussed here https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/16243#issuecomment-622452276

Answer (score 3):

Add `.AsEnumerable()` for the first query before `.Union` would fix the issue

to be as following

```
public async Task<object> GetUnitsForDataTableAsync() =>
    
        await context.Units
         .Where(x => !x.TractUnitJunctions.Any())
          .Select(x => new
          {
              x.Id,
              x.UnitName,
              x.UnitAcres,
              TractNum = String.Empty,
              Wells = String.Empty,
              NumOfWells = 0,
          }).AsEnumerable()
          .Union(
                    context.TractUnitJunctions
                    .Select(x => new
                     {
                        Id = x.UnitId,
                        x.Unit.UnitName,
                        x.Unit.UnitAcres,
                        x.Tract.TractNum,
                        Wells = string.Join(", ", x.TractUnitJunctionWellJunctions
                                          .Select(z => $"{z.Well.WellNum} ({z.Well.ApiNum})")
                                    ),
                        NumOfWells = x.TractUnitJunctionWellJunctions.Count()
             }))
            .ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Doesn't this just do the union in memory instead? How is this an answer?

Comment: You're not solving the problem. It's just cutting corners. If you need to order the final data in the database, it won't be useful.

Comment: Nooo ! AsEnumerable will do client side evaluation...so all data fetched !

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of EF Core and I don't think it will be resolved ever.
First list is easily translatable to the SQL, but second list is eager loading query with client side evaluation part and you cannot use it with Concat function. So you have to run two queries and make union on the client side.

Anyway this query can be easily written by the SQL (depends on dialect) without Concat and eager loading. Or via LINQ with appropriate extension (will provide solution on request)

Comment: requesting the solution

Comment: @TropinAlexey, you are not OP. If you have query which cannot translate create new SO question.

Answer (score -1):

**Using LINQ to SQL let keyword**
Today, I also encountered such a problem, which was solved in this way!
You can try changing it like this:

```
    (from u in context.Units
    let TractNum= String.Empty
    let Wells = String.Empty  
    let NumOfWells = 0
    select new 
    {
       u.Id,
       u.UnitName,
       u.UnitAcres,
       TractNum 
       Wells
       NumOfWells
    }).union(
    from u in context.Units
    let TractNum= String.Empty
    let Wells = String.Empty  
    let NumOfWells = 0
    select new 
    {
       u.Id,
       u.UnitName,
       u.UnitAcres,
       TractNum 
       Wells
       NumOfWells
    }
    )
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: I mean, it's not right，like this“  TractNum = String.Empty,Wells = String.Empty,NumOfWells = 0”，External assignment required

Comment: So...? I don't see that in your answer. The code as such doesn't come near to a solution.

Comment: You can try not to return these fields: tracknum, wells, numofwells. Maybe you can know better