# EF Core Union on IQueryable fails with Unable to translate set operation after client projection has been applied

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, iqueryable

I'm trying to apply `.Union` on two `IQueryable<ReviewAndReleaseDto>` queries. Unfortunately, when it reaches the Union call, it fails with:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to translate set operation after client projection has been applied. Consider moving the set operation before the last 'Select' call.

```cs
var dataSet1 = from f in _marketTransaction.GetDbSet()
    join c in _commodityRepository.GetDbSet() on f.CommodityId equals c.Id
    join p in _productRepository.GetDbSet() on c.ProductId equals p.Id
    join h in _hedgeAccountRepository.GetDbSet() on f.MarketAccount equals h.Account into gha
    from account in gha.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join con in _contractRepository.GetDbSet() on f.ContractId equals con.Id into contract
    from ct in contract.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join off in _offerRepository.GetDbSet() on f.OfferId equals off.Id into offer
    from of in offer.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join cusForCon in _customerRepository.GetDbSet() on ct.CustomerId equals cusForCon.Id into customerForContract
    from customerForCon in customerForContract.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join cusForOff in _customerRepository.GetDbSet() on of.CustomerId equals cusForOff.Id into customerForOffer
    from customerForOff in customerForOffer.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where f.IsActive == true && employeeLocations.Any(em => em.LocationId == ct.DeliveryLocationId || em.LocationId == of.DeliveryLocationId)
    select new ReviewAndReleaseDto(f.Id, customerForCon.FirstName, customerForCon.LastName, customerForCon.Number, f.CreatedOn, f.UpdatedOn, true, f.FuturesPrice, f.IsSell, f.MarketAccount,
        f.WasAcknowledge, f.PassFill, f.IsGtc, f.Expiration, f.Lots, f.WorkingLots, c.ProductId, p.Code, f.MarketPrice, f.FuturesMonth,
        f.MarketId, account.Name, f.InternalCode, f.Source == EMarketTransactionSource.Contract ? EMarketTransactionSource.Contract :
        f.Source == EMarketTransactionSource.Accumulation ? EMarketTransactionSource.Accumulation :
        f.Source == EMarketTransactionSource.Offer ? EMarketTransactionSource.Offer : EMarketTransactionSource.ExternalFill, f.Type == EMarketTransactionType.Market ? EMarketTransactionType.Market : EMarketTransactionType.Limit, f.Event == ETransactionEvent.Creation ? ETransactionEvent.Creation :
        f.Event == ETransactionEvent.Edition ? ETransactionEvent.Edition :
        f.Event == ETransactionEvent.Cancelation ? ETransactionEvent.Cancelation :
        f.Event == ETransactionEvent.Roll ? ETransactionEvent.Roll :
        f.Event == ETransactionEvent.Book ? ETransactionEvent.Book :
        f.Event == ETransactionEvent.RollBack ? ETransactionEvent.RollBack :
        f.Event == ETransactionEvent.PartiallyFilled ? ETransactionEvent.PartiallyFilled :
        f.Event == ETransactionEvent.Filled ? ETransactionEvent.Filled : ETransactionEvent.Completed, f.State.Value == EMarketTransactionState.Ready ? EMarketTransactionState.Ready :
        f.State.Value == EMarketTransactionState.Denied ? EMarketTransactionState.Denied :
        f.State.Value == EMarketTransactionState.Pending ? EMarketTransactionState.Pending :
        f.State.Value == EMarketTransactionState.Working ? EMarketTransactionState.Working :
        f.State.Value == EMarketTransactionState.PartiallyFilled ? EMarketTransactionState.PartiallyFilled :
        f.State.Value == EMarketTransactionState.Filled ? EMarketTransactionState.Filled :
        f.State.Value == EMarketTransactionState.Canceled ? EMarketTransactionState.Canceled :
        f.State.Value == EMarketTransactionState.Rejected ? EMarketTransactionState.Rejected :
        EMarketTransactionState.Expired);

var dataSet2 = from f in _offerMonitoringRepository.GetDbSet()
    join o in _offerRepository.GetDbSet() on f.OfferId equals o.Id
    join c in _commodityRepository.GetDbSet() on o.CommodityId equals c.Id
    join p in _productRepository.GetDbSet() on c.ProductId equals p.Id
    join cusForOf in _customerRepository.GetDbSet() on o.CustomerId equals cusForOf.Id
    where f.Action.Value == EOfferMonitorAction.Add && employeeLocations.Any(el => o.LocationId == el.LocationId)
    select new ReviewAndReleaseDto(f.Id, cusForOf.FirstName, cusForOf.LastName, cusForOf.Number, f.CreatedOn, f.UpdatedOn, false, o.FuturesPrice ?? 0, !o.IsSell, 0,
        false, false, o.Gtc, o.Expiration, (int)(o.Quantity / c.LotFactor), 0, c.ProductId, p.Code, o.FreightPrice, o.FuturesMonth,
        "", "", o.InternalCode, EMarketTransactionSource.Offer, EMarketTransactionType.Limit, f.Action.Value == EOfferMonitorAction.Cancel ? ETransactionEvent.Cancelation :
        f.Action.Value == EOfferMonitorAction.Add ? ETransactionEvent.Creation : ETransactionEvent.Edition, EMarketTransactionState.Pending);

var query = dataSet1.Union(dataSet2);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't process set operations after client evaluation efcore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64647224/cant-process-set-operations-after-client-evaluation-efcore)

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, no, it doesn't.

Comment: Put `AsEnumerable` and Union entities on client-side. EF Core is VERY limited for `Union` and `Concat`. If you expect it to work via `IQueryable` you will fail.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv where should I put it?

Comment: `var query = dataSet1.ToList().Union(dataSet2);` - better `ToList()` otherwise EF Core will fail that reader already opened.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, the problem is with the following filters https://pastebin.com/HEL7a42k. `.WhereIf` is not part of `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: Try `query = ApplyFilters(request, dataSet1).ToList().Concat(ApplyFilters(request, dataSet2))`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I don't think that's causing it. I tried `dataSet1.Union(dataSet1);` and it still didn't work. (concatenating the same dataset without duplicates)

Comment: But I'm pretty sure that this is EF limitation. Well you can wait for another answer.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, problem solved mate. Thanks for your time tho! `select new Model` had to be a mutable object or an anonymous one.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Apparently `ReviewAndReleaseDto` had to be mutable (anonymous object works too). It used to be a `record` which is immutable.

```cs
public class ReviewAndReleaseDto
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I'd consider trying to use EF Core and LINQ as if they were SQL a far worse problem. There are no Datasets in ORMs, there are application entities and objects. ORMs are used to allow working with data as if we were using application objects, not to embed SQL in C# code. It's the ORM's job to generate the JOINs from relations between entities. And the `Repository` pattern is meant to hide data access, not bring it into the application code itself. A DbContext already is a multi-entity repository, it doesn't need wrappers.

Comment: Is the `Union` meant to combine different subtypes? EF uses inheritance for this, mapping different types to two or more tables.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I completely agree with you. The Repository pattern is not needed with EF Core but unfortunately this project already had it, so there is nothing I can do about. Repositories are good for Dapper. To your second question, yes.

Comment: It doesn't though, those non-repositories in the end act as just wrappers to DbSet. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to write these queries at all. You can use proper relations in the entities and eliminate 80% of this code

Comment: Can you give a code example of what you mean (e.g. good/bad) because it's a bit hard for me to understand