EF Core 8 - Unable to translate set operation after client projection has been applied
I'm trying to do a union over 2 different tables but I started getting this error since updating to EF Core 8. The full error message is:

InvalidOperationException: Unable to translate set operation after
client projection has been applied. Consider moving the set operation
before the last 'Select' call.

Here is my code:
            var query = dbContext.Servicing
                .Include(s => s.Customer)
                .Include(s => s.Pictures)
                .Where(s => s.CustomerId == customerId)
                .Where(i => i.Pictures.Count > 0)
                .Select(s => new SiteVisit
                {
                    Id = s.Id,
                    CustomerId = s.CustomerId,
                    CustomerName = s.Customer.Name,
                    Date = s.ServiceDate,
                    Category = SiteVisitCategory.Service,
                    ServicingPictures = s.Pictures,
                    InstallPictures = new List<Picture>(),
        
                })

                .Union(dbContext.Installs
                    .Include(i => i.Order)
                    .Include(i => i.Pictures)
                    .Where(i => i.Order.CustomerId == customerId)
                    .Where(i => i.Pictures.Count > 0)
                    .Select(i => new SiteVisit
                    {
                        Id = i.Id,
                        CustomerId = i.Order.CustomerId,
                        CustomerName = i.Order.CustomerName,
                        Date = i.InstallDate,
                        Category = SiteVisitCategory.Install,
                        InstallPictures = i.Pictures,
                        ServicingPictures = new List<Picture>()                       
                     
                    }))

                .OrderByDescending(v => v.Date)
                .AsNoTracking();

            var queryResults = await query.ToListAsync();

I've tried moving the 'Where' clauses but I keep getting the error.
Can anyone suggest other things I can try?
Thanks to everyone for their input. Apologies for not clarifying the SiteVisit class is a POCO. It seems EF Core isn't able to handle projections that involve more than just simple property assignments. I can only assume earlier versions of EF did the UNION entirely in memory. In the end I used CONCAT (the data will be unique anyway) with separate queries (on the advice from some of the contributors) to retrieve the pictures. It doesn't read as elegantly as the original but it works. Thanks again

Can this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75545651/ef-core-union-on-iqueryable-fails-with-unable-to-translate-set-operation-after-c

Strange, try remove all includes and AsNotracking. These instructions should be ignored automatically. But I think problem in ServicingPictures = new List<Picture>(). Remove that, creating new List is not translatable to the SQL.

Also problem can be collection properties s.Pictures. Eager loading with Union is not possible, it is posible with Concat, but I’m not sure that EF Core is smart enough in this case.

There are a few issues that EF is not going to be able to resolve through a union, while it might seem nice to be able to get all of the information out in a single query, your best options will most likely be to extract the items in separate queries, combining the results after in memory (since you are loading the data anyways) or potentially unioning the base data and fetching the images separately. One detail I would strongly recommend when using projection to this site visit DTO/ViewModel is to avoid mixing DTOs and entities. In this case, storing references to Picture entities within the SiteVisit. Ideally project these out to POCO DTO classes as well with just the fields from Picture you need. Even if the majority of fields are needed it saves confusion down the road as to whether when working with a Picture, is it a tracked entity or some detached and potentially deserialized representation that originated from an entity.
Option 1: In-memory union:
var serviceSiteVisits = await dbContext.Servicing
    .Where(s => s.CustomerId == customerId)
    .Where(i => i.Pictures.Count > 0)
    .Select(s => new SiteVisit
    {
        Id = s.Id,
        CustomerId = s.CustomerId,
        CustomerName = s.Customer.Name,
        Date = s.ServiceDate,
        Category = SiteVisitCategory.Service,
        ServicingPictures = s.Pictures.Select(p => new PictureDto
        {
            Id = p.Id,
            // ..
        }).ToList()
     }).ToListAsync();

var installSiteVisits = await dbContext.Installs
    .Where(i => i.Order.CustomerId == customerId)
    .Where(i => i.Pictures.Count > 0)
    .Select(i => new SiteVisit
    {
        Id = i.Id,
        CustomerId = i.Order.CustomerId,
        CustomerName = i.Order.CustomerName,
        Date = i.InstallDate,
        Category = SiteVisitCategory.Install,
        InstallPictures = i.Pictures.Selectp => new PictureDto
        {
            Id = p.Id,
            // ..
        }).ToList()
    }).ToListAsync();

var results = serviceSiteVisits.Concat(installSiteVisits)
    .OrderByDescending(v => v.Date)
    .ToList();

In your SiteVisit ViewModel, (and entities) have collection references self-initialize to avoid having code in projections/populations being responsible for initialization. Entities for instance should never expose public setters for collections as misuse of these can mess up change tracking. For example:
  public ICollection<PictureDto> ServicingPictures { get; protected set; } = new List<PictureDto>();

Option 2: Union double-projection with Pictures loaded separately.
var initialResults = await dbContext.Servicing
    .Where(s => s.CustomerId == customerId)
    .Where(i => i.Pictures.Count > 0)
    .Select(s => new 
    {
        Id = s.Id,
        CustomerId = s.CustomerId,
        CustomerName = s.Customer.Name,
        Date = s.ServiceDate,
        Category = SiteVisitCategory.Service,
        ServicingPictureIds = s.Pictures.Select(p => p.Id).ToList(),
        InstallPictureIds = new List<int>(),
    })
    .Union(dbContext.Installs
        .Where(i => i.Order.CustomerId == customerId)
        .Where(i => i.Pictures.Count > 0)
        .Select(i => new 
        {
            Id = i.Id,
            CustomerId = i.Order.CustomerId,
            CustomerName = i.Order.CustomerName,
            Date = i.InstallDate,
            Category = SiteVisitCategory.Install,
            InstallPictureIds = i.Pictures.Select(p => p.Id).ToList(),
            ServicingPictureIds = new List<int>()                       
        })).OrderByDescending(v => v.Date)
            .ToListAsync();

var pictureIds = initialResults.SelectMany(x => x.ServicePictureIds)
    .Concat(initialResults.SelectMany(x => x.InstallPictureIds))
    .ToList();
var pictures = await dbContext.Pictures
    .Where(p => pictureIds.Contains(p.Id))
    .Select(p => new PictureDto
    {
        Id = p.Id,
        // ...
    }).ToListAsync();

var results = interimResults
    .Select(x => new SiteVisit
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        CustomerId = x.CustomerId,
        CustomerName = x.CustomerName,
        Date = x.Date,
        Category = x.Category,
        ServicingPictures = x.ServicingPictureIds
            .Select(pId => pictures.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == pId))
            .ToList();
        InstallPictures = x.InstallPictureIds
            .Select(pId => pictures.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == pId))
            .ToList();
    }).ToList();

Honestly after writing all that, it still may not even work so I'd recommend sticking to the simpler option 1. :) Double-projection can be used to help get out of sticky situations where there are properties or such that EF cannot translate down to SQL. Project the raw values first into anonymous types then perform a second, in-memory projection that performs the step(s) that cannot translate to get your final results.

Union for such different result sets has no sense. I have made such crazy Eager loading resolving for linq2db but only for Concat, when you can mark in SQL which projection apply to appropriate part of the query. Turned gray again... And yes, better two queries, but I thought about later pagination and other "obvious" non working things.

Yeah, if they need pagination then option 2 would essentially be necessary, but in cases where there are potentially a large number of results I would be simplifying the result DTO to avoid things like loading all pictures (which could potentially include large blocks of data) or other "HasMany" relationships and stick to simpler, smaller summary DTOs. Additional details like images etc. can be loaded asynchronously as needed, such as when clicking on/expanding a selected item.

In the end I did something similar to option 2 involving multiple queries. Thanks for the help

You need to union the outer values before re-joining subqueries to get the inner values.
Note that Include makes no sense when using a DTO just to retrieve the data, unless it has relationships already set up. It definitely doesn't make sense to use if the final result does not actually include Servicing or Installs, only the DTO.
Note also that Union doesn't make sense here as they will always be different. Use Concat instead for efficiency.
var servicesQuery = dbContext.Servicing
    .Where(s => s.CustomerId == customerId)
    .Where(i => i.Pictures.Count > 0)
    .Select(s => new SiteVisit
    {
        Id = s.Id,
        CustomerId = s.CustomerId,
        CustomerName = s.Customer.Name,
        Date = s.ServiceDate,
        Category = SiteVisitCategory.Service,
    });

var installsQuery = dbContext.Installs
    .Where(i => i.Order.CustomerId == customerId)
    .Where(i => i.Pictures.Count > 0)
    .Select(i => new SiteVisit
    {
        Id = i.Id,
        CustomerId = i.Order.CustomerId,
        CustomerName = i.Order.CustomerName,
        Date = i.InstallDate,
        Category = SiteVisitCategory.Install,
    });

var query = servicesQuery.Concat(installsQuery)
    .Select(i => new SiteVisit
    {
        Id = i.Id,
        CustomerId = i.CustomerId,
        CustomerName = i.CustomerName,
        Date = i.Date,
        Category = i.Category,
        InstallPictures =
             dbContext.Pictures.Where(p =>
                i.Category == SiteVisitCategory.Install
                && p.Installs.Any(s => s.Id == i.Id)
            ).ToList(),
        ServicingPictures =
            dbContext.Pictures.Where(p =>
                i.Category == SiteVisitCategory.Service
                && p.Services.Any(s => s.Id == i.Id)
            ).ToList(),
    })
    .OrderByDescending(v => v.Date)
    .AsSplitQuery()
    .AsNoTracking();

