# Unable to process Union query in Entity Framework Core 7

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, union

Using EF Core 7, I get this error:

> Unable to translate set operation after client projection has been applied. Consider moving the set operation before the last 'Select' call.

when I am trying to execute this code:

```
public async Task<List<SearchResultDto>> GeneralSearch(string searchText)
{
    var combinedSearchResult = await _cityLanguageRepository.AsQueryable()
        .Where(c => c.LanguageId == LanguageId)
        .Where(c => c.Name.Contains(searchText))
        .Select(c => new SearchResultDto
        {
            ItemId = c.CityId,
            ItemText = $"{c.Name}, {c.City.Country.CountryLanguages.FirstOrDefault(p => p.LanguageId == LanguageId).Name}",
            SearchType = SearchType.City
        })
        .Take(5)
        .Union(_locationLanguageRepository.AsQueryable()
            .Where(c => c.LanguageId == LanguageId)
            .Where(c => c.Name.Contains(searchText) ||
                        c.Location.City.CityLanguages.Any(cl => cl.LanguageId == LanguageId && cl.Name.Contains(searchText)))
            .Select(c => new SearchResultDto
            {
                ItemId = c.LocationId,
                ItemText =
                    $"{c.Name}, {c.Location.City.CityLanguages.FirstOrDefault(cl => cl.LanguageId == LanguageId).Name}, {c.Location.City.Country.CountryLanguages.FirstOrDefault(p => p.LanguageId == LanguageId).Name}",
                SearchType = SearchType.Location
            })
            .Take(5)
        )
        .Take(10)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .ToListAsync();

    return combinedSearchResult;
}
```

[I have already tried this solutions but it did not work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64647224/cant-process-set-operations-after-client-evaluation-efcore)

I also tried this:

```
var result = await _cityLanguageRepository.AsQueryable().Select(c => new
    {
        ItemId = c.CityId,
        ItemText = $"{c.Name}, {c.City.Country.CountryLanguages.FirstOrDefault(p => p.LanguageId == LanguageId).Name}",
        SearchType = SearchType.City
    }).Union(_locationLanguageRepository.AsQueryable().Select(c => new
    {
        ItemId = c.LocationId,
        ItemText =
                $"{c.Name}, {c.Location.City.CityLanguages.FirstOrDefault(cl => cl.LanguageId == LanguageId).Name}, {c.Location.City.Country.CountryLanguages.FirstOrDefault(p => p.LanguageId == LanguageId).Name}",
        SearchType = SearchType.Location
    })).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

The set operation (Union) is being performed after a client projection (Select) has been applied.

Here's an updated version of your code:

```
public async Task<List<SearchResultDto>> GeneralSearch(string searchText)
{
    var cityQuery = _cityLanguageRepository.AsQueryable()
        .Where(c => c.LanguageId == LanguageId)
        .Where(c => c.Name.Contains(searchText))
        .Select(c => new SearchResultDto
        {
            ItemId = c.CityId,
            ItemText = $"{c.Name}, {c.City.Country.CountryLanguages.FirstOrDefault(p => p.LanguageId == LanguageId).Name}",
            SearchType = SearchType.City
        })
        .Take(5);

    var locationQuery = _locationLanguageRepository.AsQueryable()
        .Where(c => c.LanguageId == LanguageId)
        .Where(c => c.Name.Contains(searchText) ||
                    c.Location.City.CityLanguages.Any(cl => cl.LanguageId == LanguageId && cl.Name.Contains(searchText)))
        .Select(c => new SearchResultDto
        {
            ItemId = c.LocationId,
            ItemText =
                $"{c.Name}, {c.Location.City.CityLanguages.FirstOrDefault(cl => cl.LanguageId == LanguageId).Name}, {c.Location.City.Country.CountryLanguages.FirstOrDefault(p => p.LanguageId == LanguageId).Name}",
            SearchType = SearchType.Location
        })
        .Take(5);

    var cityResults = await cityQuery.ToListAsync();
    var locationResults = await locationQuery.ToListAsync();

    var combinedSearchResult = cityResults.Concat(locationResults)
                                          .Take(10)
                                          .ToList();

    return combinedSearchResult;
}
```

Hope it's help

Comment: Thank you for answer. Unfortunately same error occured when I tried this.

Comment: @omerfurkandogruyol i update answer please check it

Comment: same error occured.

Comment: @omerfurkandogruyol i update answer please check it now

Comment: The last answer worked, thank you. But I still wonder can't we solve it with using Union or Concat operators with single query instead of awaiting 2 queries?

Comment: @omerfurkandogruyol In Entity Framework Core 7, the translation of Union operations is limited, and in some cases, it may not be supported when used in combination with client-side projection. This limitation can result in the error message you're seeing.